# Is this language allowed?

Tags: discussion, rules

I invented a new programming language, called CodeGolfSolver. When running a program, it converts the characters to digits in base `1114111`, interprets it as a number, and solves the problem described at the url `codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/< number in base 10 here >` at the date depending upon the version (see note). in an optimal manner. Example Program

```
摦
```

This program is capable of detecting the [heartbleed exploit](http://heartbleed.com). My question is: Are we allowed to use the programming language `CodeGolfSolver` to solve challenges on this site.

Note: There are different versions. For example, CodeGolfSolver-2014-4-12 is based on the codegolf site as of 2014/4/12. Compilers and intrepreters are recommended to make copies of the site for each version they support.

Note: This post itself is an interpreter in the [English programming language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/English). It is freely available.

Comment: No. This is a variant of a [well-known cheat](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1085/3) which we do not allow.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Fixed

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young not to mention it just fetches the question, not any of the answers when you download a complier or intrepreter.

Comment: I don't really understand these "Look at me!!! How smart I am" answers. Noone cares if you think you found a loophole. They are just guidelines. We are not lawyers here - You'll get downvoted anyway. To me these answers are just saying "Look at me - I'm too stupid to write real answers but I'm craving attention"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Comment: @pppery Just imagine what can happen if somebody *answers* this heavily downvoted question from 2014!

Answer (score 20):

... could you just use common sense?

---

If you seriously actually need an enumeration of why exactly this is invalid (which I doubt):

- you need to provide a working, freely available interpreter, which means solving every single challenge on the site
- languages (including versions of languages) created after the challenge are invalid
- it's cheating (obviously) and you'll get showered in downvotes
- it also violates one of the "standard loopholes," specifically https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/3808

Comment: So GHC 7.8.1 would be invalid for some of the challenges?

Comment: @PyRulez What is GHC 7.8.1...?

Comment: A dialect of haskell, sort of. It is the newest GHC compiler for haskell. It was recently released.

Comment: Also, I added an interpreter.

Comment: Also, for point 4, it is part of the language itself.

Comment: There is also a rule for point 2: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny/1071#1071

Comment: Just to clarify this for the OP: if you decided to write a new language with a builtin for every single challenge submitted to PPCG so far, and actually succeeded in implementing it, it'd be a pretty interesting and valid golfing language — but it wouldn't automatically expand to cover *newly submitted* challenges, and might or might not be competitive on them (although you can probably do some pretty crazy things using only PPCG challenges as builtins).

Answer (score -1):

### Yes, it's fine

If you can implement an interpreter that can parse a description of a problem in English and solve it, go ahead. But I think you'd have to count the description of the problem in the byte count.

The actual loophole that's implicitly being violated here though is https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/30512 - you can't use a version of an interpreter newer than the problem.